# Why @PostConstruct called twice on @Singleton

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jersey, jax-rs

I am running a simple .war file under Glassfish 4.0-b87 that was created in Eclipse Kepler M6 using M2E as a simple project with Dynamic Web Module facet added, using Oracle Java 7 JDK/JVM.

There is essentially a single class for which I expect the `post_construct` method to be called exactly once. But it is called twice, first when the app is deployed, and one more time on the first and only the first HTTP request.

Here is the class (the log output follows):

```
package com.example.main;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.PostActivate;
import javax.ejb.PrePassivate;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.PassivationCapable;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@Singleton
@Startup
@LocalBean
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
@Path("/life")
public class Life extends Application implements PassivationCapable {

  @PostConstruct
  public void post_construct () {
    System.out.println("hello world!");
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void pre_destroy () {
    System.out.println("so long and thanks for the fish!");
  }

  @PrePassivate
  public void pre_passivate () {
    System.out.println("taking a break");
  }

  @PostActivate
  public void post_activate () {
    System.out.println("back from break");
  }

  @Override
  public String getId () {
    return "life";
  }

  @GET
  public String greet () {
    return "hi";
  }
}
```

The log output is as follows with a dashed line separating the part before the first HTTP call and the part after the HTTP call:

```
[2013-05-09T19:42:26.660-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-DEPLOYMENT-00027] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.autodeploy] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546660] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Selecting file /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/singleton.war for autodeployment]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.692-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546692] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.702-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546702] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.706-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546706] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.709-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546709] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.749-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [ejb.portable_jndi_names] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546749] [levelValue: 800] [[
  EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB Life: [java:global/singleton/Life, java:global/singleton/Life!com.example.main.Life]]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.959-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546959] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-001473 javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean implementation org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension$LocalBean@cbcbf4a declared a normal scope but does not implement javax.enterprise.inject.spi.PassivationCapable. It won't be possible to inject this bean into a bean with passivating scope (@SessionScoped, @ConversationScoped). This can be fixed by assigning the Bean implementation a unique id by implementing the PassivationCapable interface.]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.970-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1368164546970] [levelValue: 800] [[
  hello world!]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.982-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546982] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registering the Jersey servlet application, named com.example.main.Life, at the servlet mapping /rest/*, with the Application class of the same name.]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:26.988-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164546988] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [singleton] at [/singleton]]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:27.003-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164547003] [levelValue: 800] [[
  singleton was successfully deployed in 332 milliseconds.]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:27.006-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-DEPLOYMENT-00035] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.autodeploy] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1368164547006] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [AutoDeploy] Successfully autodeployed : /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/singleton.war.]]
```

------------------------------AFTER FIRST HTTP CALL------------------------------

```
[2013-05-09T19:42:44.940-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1368164564940] [levelValue: 800] [[
  hello world!]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:44.940-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1368164564940] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0-rc2 2013-04-23 12:04:25...]]

[2013-05-09T19:42:44.956-1000] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.EjbComponentProvider] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1368164564956] [levelValue: 800] [[
  The Jersey EJB interceptor is bound. JAX-RS EJB integration support is enabled.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`<update>`** this is a Glassfish bug https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20505 **`</update>`**

It seems that `@Singleton`, and `@ApplicationPath` + `extends Application` are not playing nice with each other. Perhaps the behavior is correct in that JAX-RS needs to instantiate the `Application` class once, and EJB needs to instantiate the `@Singleton` once, but until somebody points to the relevant part of the standards it is best to consider it as a bug. Jersey should recognize the `@Singleton` annotation and look for the `extends Application` class rather than creating its own.

The workaround for the probable Jersey bug is to not use the same class as both `@Singleton` and the Jersey `Application` class.

Comment: This is not a bug. You're basically tight-coupling a webservice and businessservice together in a single class. You end up with two entirely separate instances of the very same class which are used for two entirely different purposes. In other words, there's just means of bad design. Just split the webservice logic and businessservice logic over two separate classes and inject the businessservice as @EJB in the webservice.

Comment: @BalusC Do you mean the @Application + @Singleton coupling? or @ApplicationPath + @Path coupling? or @Singleton + @Path. I completely agree about bad design, but a bad design can very well expose a Glassfish implementation bug. I think separating @Path into one class and @Singleton + @ApplicationPath in one class significantly improves the design, but I bet it will still expose the Glassfish implementation bug where it creates instantiates a new `extends Application` class when an instance already exists. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Look at the packages where those annotations come from. `javax.ws.rs` is JAX-RS webservice API. `javax.ejb` is EJB businessservice API.

Comment: @BalusC Here is a pretty authoritative reference from Oracle itself that shows how you can put a webservice annotation and a businessservice annotation on the same class. See Listing 4 in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jaxrs20-1929352.html So that part of your argument is not compelling.

Comment: Adam Bien is a Java EE evangelist. Take his articles with a little grain of salt as to "best practices". His sole goal in this kind of articles is to show off the "slickness" of Java EE 6 and get rid of the common consensus that Java EE is "heavy". Fact is, you're this way essentially creating 2 completely distinct instances, which do not share their state in any way. Whether you find that sensible or not is up to you, but IMO this is not. This is clearly tight coupling.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for your opinion. I completely agree with the better design suggestion, but I disagree on whether there is a bug in Glassfish. My main focus in this question is on the Glassfish bug since buggy containers help nobody. I have reported it and I will post the dev-team's assessment. BY THE WAY, another question I could use your wisdom on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491243/how-to-write-main-using-cdi-in-java-ee

Comment: I have nowhere said that this is a bug in Glassfish. This is fully expected behavior. If you call `new SomeObject()` twice, then you also don't complain that its constructor is invoked twice. This is exactly what is happing under the covers. JAX-RS is been told to instantiate and use class X as webservice. EJB is been told to instantiate and use class X as businessservice. They know nothing from each other.

Comment: @Balusc yes, of course I understand you consider it to not be a bug. It was just my understanding that in a unified Java EE spec that includes JAX-RS and EJB, the two components should know something about each other. I am more likely wrong than you are but when there is a unifying standard that talks about both sub-standards I look for a reference to text in the standard before accepting it as expected behavior. for what it's worth, the Glassfish people have not yet closed it as not-a-bug. I will know soon! Thanks again!

Comment: @BalusC Glassfish / Jersey team acknowledges this as a bug expected to be fixed in 4.0.1  They do not say there is any violation of standards in my example, i. e. mixing and matching ejb and web tier. See: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20505

Comment: @BalusC here is the final word on whether JAX-RS "webservice" and EJB "businesservice" "know nothing from each other". The EJB 3.2 standard was released today. It includes the paragraph: "In a product that supports the JAX-RS specification, stateless and singleton session beans must be supported as root resource classes, providers, and `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` subclasses. JAX-RS annotations may be applied to a session bean class, methods of a session bean’s no-interface view, or a session bean’s local business interface."