# How to write main() using CDI in Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, seam3, weld, java-ee-7

I have a no-client application that I wish to run. It will have no clients but it will make HTTP calls and act as client for other services. It would run for perhaps a few hours or days (but it will not require periodic runs -- just one-shot).

I want to run it in a Java EE 7 container, because of the benefits of standard Context Dependency Injection (CD), and a standard JAX-RS client (new since Java EE 7). It is also nice to have services such as JMS, JPA.

The question is how do I write / annotate the main method in a standard way? `@Inject` on a method is no good because such methods must return quickly. `@Schedule` is not ideal because it runs periodically unless I programmatically determine current system time.

The best I could come up with is to set a one-shot `Timer` in an `@Inject` method and annotate my main method with `@Timeout`.

Somehow this seems a bit fragile or inelegant. **Is there a better standard way to start the service?** Some annotation that would just cause it to start and get going?

Additionally, how **what is the best standard way to interrupt and shut down the service upon undeployment**?

Comment: Your question is a little meandering. If you are running the application in an app container then why are you defining a main method? Just create a startup singleton EJB with a [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) method.

Comment: @Perception the meandering is a reflection of my lack of clarity, hence the question. `@Schedule` takes a time. What time should I annotate the method with? I do not want it to be run periodically. The method needs to be run exactly once. If `@Schedule` accepts an interval after deployment that would be perfect, but it doesn't. Could I use an `@Schedule ... myfunc (Timer timer)` and cancel the incoming timer and use `TimerService` set an interval timer to run `@Timeout ... mymain ()` sounds involved.

Comment: Don't know if you edited your question or I missed the bottom part. Would swear it read different. Anyway, one idea - use a startup, singleton bean and create a timer in its @PostConstruct method. Or, embed a third party library like Quartz and schedule a non-recurring job to kick off the job when your application is deployed. What are the schedule requirements for the job (on app deployment, particular day, run on demand?).

Comment: @Perception may be it was your perception ;-) I did not edit and if I did the edits would be available. I DID edit my username after your last comment. The schedule requirement is "on app deployment". Thank you for the suggestions. I prefer not to use the third-party library but I will try the `@PostConstruct` timer.

Comment: @Perception (continued) regarding shut down, is it ok to have `@PreDestroy` set a flag and wait on a lock held by the main method which is released when main notices the flag and ends? Essentially I want to stop on undeploy and start on deploy without any other manual or non-standard techniques.

Comment: My perception might be affected by all the cough syrup I'm downing. If your job will be long running then you might be better served calling an `@Asynchronous` method from the `@PostConstruct` of your SLSB. You will have to design your task to be interruptible and trigger said interruption from a `@PreDestroy` callback.

Comment: great suggestion on `@Asynchronous`! but i don't know how to call it asynchronously from `@PostConstruct` - without a proxy it works a synchronous call. my "main" method and postconstruct are in the same `@Singleton` class. need a self-proxy in postconstruct.

Comment: @Perception hope you are feeling better. `@Asynchronous` helped but I am running into a different problem. I can work around it but I would like to report it to Glassfish as a bug if it really is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493381/cannot-cancel-asynchronous-call-to-ejb

Comment: @Perception - that's not a bug btw. Additionally with the `@Asynchronous` please see my comment on answer by @JanGalinsky below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the `EJB` with(or instead of) `CDI`, then try the `@Singleton` + `@Startup` annotations for your bean, and `@PostConstruct` for your `main()` method.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class YourBean {

@Stateless
public static class BeanWithMainMethod{

    @Asynchronous
    public void theMainMethod(){
        System.out.println("Async invocation");
     }
}

    @EJB
    private BeanWithMainMethod beanWithMainMethod;

    @PostConstruct
    private void launchMainMethod(){
        beanWithMainMethod.theMainMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: i thought the container will kill it if `@PostConstruct` does not return soon enough. have you tried this with a long running method?

Comment: Deployment will fail if theMainMethod does not return for a long time, so, better practice is to use @Asyncronous or CDI events.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, upvoted for the correction (would be nice if you could edit your answer too!)

Comment: the code is OK but the text above the code doesn't match the code. it should say: "annotate your main method with `@Asynchronous` and invoke it from a `@PostConstruct` method after self-injecting the bean using `@EJB`"

Answer (score 4):

When PostConstruct is long running, decouple with events:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class YourBean{
@Inject
private Event<XXX> started; 
@PostConstruct
private void theMainMethod(){
    started.fire(new XXX());
}
public void handleStarted(@Observes XXX started) {
    // the real main method.
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you @JanGalinski by the way the other option was to use an `@Asynchronous public void handleStarted ()` but I could not get it to be called asynchronously from within the `@PostConstruct` method. Which do you think is better - `@Asynchronous` or `@Observes`? Any idea what I need to do to make an asynchronous call to a method in the same bean from within `@PostConstruct` in the same bean too? Thanks for the great suggestion in the meanwhile.

Comment: Well, there is no standard way to request cancellation of an `@Observes` method. With `@Asynchronous` one can request cancellation of the method through the `Future` that is returned. While this can be simulated in a non-standard way, in a future version of Java EE the programmer is likely to be able to request that a standard cancellation request actually interrupt the thread while it is in a blocking call which would greatly improve its responsiveness and clean up the structure too. This expected functionality cannot be implemented by the programmer on her own. Thus `@Asynchronous` wins IMO.